# Determine number of visible Gtk.FlowBox children

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm using a `Gtk.FlowBox` with a number of `Gtk.FlowBoxChild` children. Based on buttons selected by a user I'm applying different `Gtk.FlowBoxFilterFunc` functions. I would like to determine at any point in time how many of the children are visible (i.e. unfiltered). I've tried checking all the various `visible`, `no_show_all` properties, as well as the `is_visible()`, `get_visible()` functions. I can't seem to find any property or method for determining which children are unfiltered - is this possible?

I've noticed that when I use the GTK Inspector for debugging, it seems to detect the change, because the text in the hierarchy tree changes from black go grey. This makes me think that it must be possible somehow!

MCVE:

```
public class Mcve.Application : Gtk.Application {

    public Application () {
        Object (
            application_id: Constants.APP_ID,
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        );
    }

    protected override void activate () {
        var flow_box = new Gtk.FlowBox () {
            expand = true
        };
        var child1 = new Gtk.FlowBoxChild ();
        child1.child = new Gtk.Label ("Child 1");
        var child2 = new Gtk.FlowBoxChild ();
        child2.child = new Gtk.Label ("Child 2");

        flow_box.add (child1);
        flow_box.add (child2);

        var button = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Filter");
        button.clicked.connect (() => {
            flow_box.set_filter_func ((child) => {
                var item = child.get_child () as Gtk.Label;
                return item.label == "Child 1";
            });
            foreach (var child in flow_box.get_children ()) {
                var item = child as Gtk.FlowBoxChild;
                int index = item.get_index () + 1;
                debug ("[Child %d] item.visible = %s", index, item.visible.to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.no_show_all = %s", index, item.no_show_all.to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.is_visible () = %s", index, item.is_visible ().to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.get_visible () = %s", index, item.get_visible ().to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.get_child ().visible = %s", index, item.get_child ().visible.to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.get_child ().no_show_all = %s", index, item.get_child ().no_show_all.to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.get_child ().is_visible () = %s", index, item.get_child ().is_visible ().to_string ());
                debug ("[Child %d] item.get_child ().get_visible () = %s", index, item.get_child ().get_visible ().to_string ());
            }
        });

        var grid = new Gtk.Grid ();
        grid.attach (flow_box, 0, 0);
        grid.attach (button, 0, 1);

        var window = new Gtk.Window ();
        window.add (grid);

        this.add_window (window);

        window.present ();
        window.show_all ();
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        var app = new Mcve.Application ();
        return app.run (args);
    }

}
```

Output when clicking to filter:

```
[Child 1] item.visible = true
[Child 1] item.no_show_all = false
[Child 1] item.is_visible () = true
[Child 1] item.get_visible () = true
[Child 1] item.get_child ().visible = true
[Child 1] item.get_child ().no_show_all = false
[Child 1] item.get_child ().is_visible () = true
[Child 1] item.get_child ().get_visible () = true
[Child 2] item.visible = true
[Child 2] item.no_show_all = false
[Child 2] item.is_visible () = true
[Child 2] item.get_visible () = true
[Child 2] item.get_child ().visible = true
[Child 2] item.get_child ().no_show_all = false
[Child 2] item.get_child ().is_visible () = true
[Child 2] item.get_child ().get_visible () = true
```

In the GTK Inspector, I can see that it somehow knows that the second child is not visible:

[image: GTK Inspector]

---

Edit: Looks like the GTK Inspector responds to the `mapped` signal: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/main/gtk/inspector/object-tree.c#L700, and indeed calling `get_mapped ()` on the `FlowBoxChild` will return `true` or `false` depending on whether the item is visible. I'm not really sure what it means for a widget to be mapped though, so I'm a bit hesitant to trust this.

Comment: I'd like to take a look. Could you please provide a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: @BobMorane - Added, thanks! Clicking the button applies the filter, and all properties etc. seem to indicate that the FlowBoxChild, as well as the child widget, would be visible.

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look as soon as I can!!

Comment: @BobMorane - I dug into the Gtk Inspector source and it looks like using `get_mapped()` works. That's a new one for me, the concept of a mapped widget isn't something I've heard of before. https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.map.html

Comment: Ok, I will check on my side as well as soon as I can. " dug into the Gtk Inspector source" : well done!

Comment: From [this](https://people.gnome.org/~ebassi/docs/_build/Gtk/4.0/signal.Widget.map.html): "A widget is mapped when the widget is visible (which is controlled with `GtkWidget:visible`) and all its parents up to the toplevel widget are also visible.

The `::map` signal can be used to determine whether a widget will be drawn".

Comment: It looks like you found it! I would recommend you test it and, if it works as expected, you post your findings as a solution.

Comment: It's working great - I wish I had looked into the GTK Inspector source yesterday! Amazing what a good night of sleep will do!

Comment: By the way, thanks for GTK Inspector... I have been developing using GTK for a while now and somehow, I never heard of that. Now looking into it... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the `get_mapped()` method on the `Gtk.FlowBoxChild` widget.

Like @BobMorane mentioned in the comments, the [GTK documentation](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eebassi/docs/_build/Gtk/3.0/signal.Widget.map.html) has the following entry for the `map` signal:

> A widget is mapped when the widget is visible (which is controlled
> with GtkWidget:visible) and all its parents up to the toplevel widget
> are also visible. The ::map signal can be used to determine whether a
> widget will be drawn

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and Gtk Inspector!